# Change the color of the ActionBar and other elemets

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to change the color scheme of my application and want to change the color of the ActionBar, menu items, etc.

I came across this tool : http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

And I used it to generate the necessary files to get everything in the color that I want to. However, when I add the files to my res directory, the theme still does not change.

Does anyone know how I can use it to change my app's color scheme to whatever I want?

Answer (score 1):

The tool you mentioned is deprecated, that means no longer supported. You should use [Toolbar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html). Which is mentioned in the android support docs. or use the [AppCompat version](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html) (to support older devices)

Comment: How exactly do I use Toolbar? It does not generate XML files for me to put in my in my res folder.

Comment: @FlameDra I linked to Android's developer documents, which is a great source of information that would be too long to explain here. Please check out one of the two links in my answer for the entire explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Look in your styles and compare it with this page https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html
Remember that style needs to be set to have effect.

Comment: If its set to any of those it does not change the colors.